# Question about SDK's

Tags: php, mongodb, sdk

I am not sure if this is a stupid question or not.

I have been working with Mongodb and found myself writing the same logic in different applications for simple stuff like selecting collections and drop them etc.

If I made some classes based on the datamapper pattern using all the Mongodb functions would this be a basic SDK ?

If I am totally wrong could someone help me out in defining a SDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're creating a reusable library or if you are getting a bit more ambitious an application framework.

My understanding of an SDK is that it would have the tools (eg. compilers, WSDL pre-processors) necessary to develop applications, whereas the Runtime Environment would just have what you need to run the developed application. Contrast a Java JRE (VM, standard libraries) and JDK (compiler etc.) When we develop for specialised platforms (eg. smart phones) we often have in the SDK an emulation of the target platform to allow us to test our code on our workstation.

I don't think you should be concerned as to whether or not you are building a framework or an SDK, rather be concerned about if it will be useful to other developers. If you say to them: "download your standard Java JDK, + standard mongodb + my excellent framework) you may well help them a lot. I would view something such as Spring as having started like that, and look what happened to that.

Once you start packaging other stuff with your framework, with the objective of making the developers initial download simpler you buy into a world of maintenance issues, when will you release a new version of your package? What happens when fixes are needed for packages you include.

Comment: The main reason to do this was too test my skills and push it all to github and get people using mongodb more, As I found when I first started using it I was baffled about certain parts.

Answer (score 2):

[Software Development Kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit)

> A software development kit (SDK or "devkit") is typically a set of development tools that allows for the creation of applications for a certain software package, software framework, hardware platform, computer system, video game console, operating system, or similar platform

Comment: So I am kinda right in saying that if I bundle all the functions mongodb use and make some reporting and monitoring tools it would be classed as a SDK ?